# Having trouble embedding Flash file into Webpage

Tags: html, flash, fullscreen

I need to make a Flash animation fullscreen. After a bit of research it seems I can only feasibly do this via a browser, since the Windows 7 preview does not support fullscreen.

I followed the steps of this website; 
http://www.bezzmedia.com/swfspot/tutorials/flash8/True_Fullscreen_Flash_Mode

However, I'm having a problem embedding the flash file into a simple HTML document. The file is called "LaBoheme.swf" and is stored in the same directory as my HTML file. Hence, here is my code;

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Test Heading</h1>

<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="laboheme.swf" width="1280" height="1024">
<param name="movie" value="laboheme.swf">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
</object>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is simply that the flash animation does not appear. I get the feeling I'm making a rookie mistake here that I just can't figure out. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="1280" height="1024" id="dewplayer" align="left">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="movie" value="laboheme.swf" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<embed src="laboheme.swf" quality="high" allowFullScreen="true" width="1280" height="1024" name="dewplayer" align="left" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" 
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed>
</object>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that still doesn't work... I tried both IE and Chrome. The movie just fails to load in both cases.

Not sure if it's relevant, that's why I didn't mention it, but I'm using Macromedia Flash 8 with Actionscript 2.

Comment: are u sure that laboheme.swf existe